# Find the PDF and the CDF of $ \sqrt X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I was doing a question in probability 1st year, the question is:

> $X$ is has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. What's the probability distribution and the density of $\sqrt{X}$?

What I have so  far is $P(\sqrt(X) < x)=P(X<x^2)$.

Now, as we know that X follows the uniform distribution then
$  =((x^2-0)/(1-0))= x^2 $

then I don't really know how to calculate the domain of the function, because when P($X <x ^2)= 1$ then $x=1$ or $x=-1$

I don't know which of both values should I take

Comment: X is non-negative, so x=1.  In any case the density for $\sqrt {X}$ is 2x in the interval [0,1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a theorem for function of random variable: Let $X$ be a continuous random variable and $Y=g(x)$ where $g(X)$ is continuous in $X$ and strictly monotonous, then $$f_Y(y)=f_X[g^{-1}(y)]\left|\cfrac {\mathrm{d}g^{-1}(y)}{\mathrm{d}y}\right| $$

So $f_Y(y)=f_X(x^2)\cfrac{\mathrm{d}y^2}{\mathrm{d}y}=2y   \qquad y\in[0,1]$

$\displaystyle F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}{0  \qquad y<0\\\int_0^y 2u\mathrm{d}u=y^2   \qquad y\in[0,1]\\1 \qquad y>1} \end{cases}$